# Psycopg2 Symbol not found: _PQbackendPID Expected in: dynamic lookup

Tags: python, django, postgresql, heroku, psycopg2

Im getting this error when trying to run python / django after installing psycopg2:

Error: dlopen(/Users/macbook/Envs/medint/lib/python2.7/site-packages/psycopg2/_psycopg.so, 2): Symbol not found: _PQbackendPID
  Referenced from: /Users/macbook/Envs/medint/lib/python2.7/site-packages/psycopg2/_psycopg.so
  Expected in: dynamic lookup

Anyone?

Answer (score 6):

on Mojave macOS, I solved it by running below steps:

- pip uninstall psycopg2
- pip install psycopg2-binary

Answer (score 2):

I think I may have solved this... but Im not sure because of how many steps I ran and re-ran thru but I wanted to leave hints for others in case they are running into the same issues.

Im on Mountain Lion 10.8.2
I ended up:

```
Install Brew  ( going thru all the brew doctor clean ups )
Install postgresql ( using Brew )
Install psycopg2 via pip install 
Install postgresApp ( native OSX app from Heroku )
Launch postgresApp
python manage.py runserver
```

now it works... or seems to.